# Executing a script on boot in lubuntu 19.04 to connect to VPN (rc.local and crontab issues)

Tags: linux, boot, vpn, crontab, lubuntu

I am new to Linux and I am wondering how to make my virtual machine with Lubuntu 19.04 **automatically connect to a VPN on boot**. the VPN I chose is **Proton VPN** and I have to execute this command to connect

```
protonvpn c -f
```

this command **has to be executed with sudo permission**, therefore, I tried to place it in */etc/ rc.local* as I have seen in multiple threads in stack overflow but **the file rc.local does not happen to exist**, I even tried to create and set it up manually without any effect

I tried, even if I know it is not a proper use, to **change crontab in root folder**, in order **to allow the command to have sudo permissions**, with the command:

```
crontab -e
```

changing the last line as follows:

```
@reboot bash /home/lubuntu/Documents/on_boot.sh
```

where *on_boot.sh* is a script, which **I have already set as executable**, containing this line:

```
protonvpn c -f
```

then I try to restart the virtual machine and when I check my IP is every time my default one, which assures me that it **does not work**

I cannot figure out the reason, I apologize in advance for my English and if I have not been extremely precise with terminology

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a service, you will find above a standard implementation of it :

1- Create a service under '/etc/systemd/system/protonvpn.service' with the above code :

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for proton vpn

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/lubuntu/Documents/on_boot.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2- Reload the new configuration from disk :

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

3- Enable your service, so it will start once the systemd has **booted** :

```
sudo systemctl enable protonvpn
```

4- Start and check the status of **protonvpn** service :

```
sudo systemctl start protonvpn
sudo systemctl status protonvpn
```

Comment: unfortunately still not working, I can see the service as activated but still does not work, the script in on_boot.sh is correct in fact if I sudo bash and then ./.../on_boot.sh my ip changes correctly